# Debugging react-native on android - com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Unexpected token '*'

Tags: react-native

So, first of all...running on iOS has no issues. I am on

> "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
>
> "react-native": "^0.49.3",

I get the following error when trying to react-native run-android on physical device or emulator.

I have also tried removing and reinstalling node modules, clearing npm cache, cleaning the android build. None of these things solve this issue.

If I go to the url in the error there is a JS page. The application also locks up the device or emulator.

Other info:

adb is my path and I can run adb devices.

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 doesn't help

```
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782): Exception in native call from JS
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782): com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Unexpected token '*' (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:112538)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782): Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Unexpected token '*' (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:112538)
10-19 12:28:20.839: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   ... 7 more
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782): Exception in native call
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782): Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
10-19 12:28:20.841: E/unknown:ReactNative(12782):   ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after much debugging I found the cause of this issue and I'll post it here incase anyone else runs into it.

My project is using the

> Exponentiation operator **

(I think this was introduced in ES6).

As I said in my question, this doesn't cause any issues when running on iOS. I haven't dug deep enough yet, but it appears that there must be a bug in the react-native code base on the Android side of things. Maybe it is in Bable? I'm not 100% sure.

What I do know however, is

> changing from, for example, 2 ** 3 to Math.pow(2,3) solves this for
>   me.

Update on this answer:

I am not able to reproduce this creating a brand new RN project. The project in which I had this problem was upgraded from RN 42, so there must be an issue with the upgrade process.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** babel-preset-react-native (v5.0.0) now supports the exponentiation operator. The preset's [package.json](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/babel-preset/package.json) requires plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator

---

It's only a matter of time until [babel-preset-react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset) supports the exponentiation operator, but for now, you can add [babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-exponentiation-operator/) to your project manually.

`yarn add babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator --dev`

Then in your `.babelrc` file, make sure your `plugins` property looks similar to this:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-exponentiation-operator"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone still got this error, try this

[** operator breaks packager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15668)

This solution fix for me, I'm not sure what cause my error though.
My react version is

> "react": "16.0.0"
>
> "react-native": "0.50.4"

In short,

```
npm install babel-preset-react-native-stage-0
```

then add this line below to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0"]
}
```

If react native is already there it'll be

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "react-native-stage-0"]
}
```